# check None in multiples variables

Tags: python

```
a = 'asd'
b = 'dsa'

if a is not None and b is not None:
    pass
```

there is any way to improve this segment of code?

Also tried:

```
if not (a is None, b is None):

if not (a, b is None):
```

Both are not working.

Comment: What are you looking for? Is it an `or`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the in-built function [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

```
a = 'asd'
b = 'dsa'

print all([a,b])
#True
```

In case one or more of the variables is `None` It would produce `False`

---

So if you want to use this with some condition, The code would be:

```
a = 'asd'
b = 'dsa'

if all([a,b]):
    print 'All True!!!!'
#All True!!!!
```

Comment: But this isn't equivalent to OP's code.  e.g. Empty strings would result in `False` here, but not in OP's original.

Comment: This solution also raises a ValueError if one of the arguments is a numpy array.

Comment: `all((a, b))` you don't need a list.

Comment: @khachik -- Here you're using a `tuple` instead.  You might want to point out why a `tuple` is better than a `list`.  I find that the list is easier for my eye to parse, but the tuple will likely execute slightly faster (though I didn't `timeit`).

Comment: @mgilson how about passing a `set`?

Comment: @KDawG -- Not sure what you mean about the `set`.  Care to elaborate?  `None in {a, b}`?  That would work in *most* cases, but the test is still not as concrete as using `is`.  If you really wanted to, you could construct class instances which aren't `None` but still look like `None` to the `set`.

Comment: @mgilson, you should use a list unless you really need it. Not likely, it is really faster, because it is immutable.

Comment: @mgilson what I meant by a set was something like this `if all({a,b}):`

Comment: @KDawG -- That does nothing more than `all((a,b))` except enforce that `a` and `b` are hashible.

Comment: @all, for two vars I would use `not (a is None or b is None)`. If you don't like it and need exactly `is None` behavior you can use `all(x is not None for x in (a, b))`.

Comment: @khachik -- There's also `not any(x is None for x in (a,b))` which might short circuit faster depending on what you expect for `a` and `b` to be on a typical case.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a better `or` ? If so you can do this -

```
>>> a = None
>>> b = 'dsa'
>>> if None in [b,a]: print "hi"
... 
hi
```

Comment: This doesn't maintain the `is` clause ...  You could have objects that aren't `None` but are equal to None which would still evaluate to `True`

Answer (score 1):

There's a version very close to your first attempt:

```
if not (a is None or b is None):
```

Though I'm not convinced that is a whole lot better ...

Answer (score 1):

```
if not(a is None or b is None)
```

Yay [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)!

Answer (score 0):

just

```
If a and b
```

is ok
`a is none` is equal to `a` in `if.. else..`

Answer (score 0):

You could Put all the values you want to test in a list. Iterate through that list and branch depending on results.  Something like

```
a = None
b = None
c = 1
values = [a,b,c]
    for v in values:
        if v == None: #or possibly just if v:
            break
```

You would replace break with whatever action you want to take if any value is not None.

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you're doing a ton, you could do:

```
def hasNone(*args):
    for i in args:
        if i is None:return True
    return False
```

and then

```
if not hasNone(a,b,etc):
    pass
```